# How to install a already imported app to a subsite in CSOM?

Tags: csom, app

I succesfully imported a custom provider hosted app to sitecollection "myCompany.com". Is it possible to install this app to a subsite by CSOM code? I found this powershell command which doing this:

```
Install-SPApp -Web < URL > -Identity $myapp
```

Is this also possible in CSOM or Office dev pnp CSOM ? I have some custom logic which is creating a subsite and I would like to have some app available in this subsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes an app can be installed to a site using CSOM **Web.LoadAndInstallApp method**,

code snippet :

```
// Unique ID for side loading feature
Guid sideloadingFeature = new Guid("AE3A1339-61F5-4f8f-81A7-ABD2DA956A7D");
// Prompt for URL
string url = GetUserInput("Please provide URL for the site where app is being installed: \n");

// Get path to the location of the app file in file system
string path = GetUserInput("Please provide full path to your app package: \n");

// Create context for SharePoint Site
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url);
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

// Get variables for the operations
Site site = ctx.Site;
Web web = ctx.Web;

try
{
// Make sure we have side loading enabled.     
site.ActivateFeature(sideloadingFeature);
try
{
    // Load .app file and install that to site
    var appstream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
    AppInstance app = web.LoadAndInstallApp(appstream);
    ctx.Load(app);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
// Disable side loading feature using 

site.DeactivateFeature(sideloadingFeature);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception!"), ex.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
Console.Read();
}
```

Refer this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/11/20/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom/ for more info on this.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: In this solution I need the app package file. Is this needed? I already imported and installed the app succesfully on top level site.

Comment: yes you need to specify the path of the .app file from the file directory

Comment: And this logic is needed for each new created subsite? Or once on the top level site ?

Comment: This  need to be applied on respective sites where the app need to be installed.

Comment: I try your code but got this error "The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID". The app is already installed on top level site. In your code example I try to install the same app on subsite, but got this error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try changing the version of the app from app manifest file and try to install it back in subsite , bcs i tried this it works fine in my case.

Comment: It was not needed to change the version number. I make a mistake in context. I was trying to install the app to the root site where the app was already installed. My target was to install the app to a subsite. When I change the context to the subsite it was working fine.